# NuGet attempting to restore wrong version

Tags: c#, nuget, bamboo

I have a C# project with the following NuGet references:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Pidac.HealthCare.Appointment.Model" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

We have our build process setup in Bamboo, which attempts to restore the NuGet packages as a preliminary step. Project builds fine on my machine, restoring the correct NuGet package and all.

The build is currently failing since Bamboo has decided to attempt restoring version 1.0.0 of Pidac.HealthCare.Appointment.Model, instead of going by what it has in packages.config.

How would this happen and what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Using NuGet? Use SemVer. If this is a NuGet you produce yourself, change to SemVer otherwise ask the author to switch to using it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're seeing [a breaking change in NuGet 3.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/dependency-versions)

> A zero in the fourth part of the version number will be omitted
>
> ```
> 1.0.0.0 is treated as 1.0.0
> 1.0.01.0 is treated as 1.0.1
> ```

It's hard to know exactly what to suggest here, partly as we don't know whether this is your own package, hosted on your own server, or something else.

Comment: It is our own package hosted on own servers.   Hoping I do not have to changing nuspec files...

Comment: @KlausNji: You *may* be able to change the server to make it return 1.0.0.0 when asked for 1.0.0. I think that's the intention, but the doc isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Jon, NuGet version on the servers is 3.3.0.212.  Would upgrading to 3.4 help?  Otherwise, how do I make this server side change?